I am encountering performance issues, especially lagging. I tried rebooting, fixed package dependencies as there was an error of unmet dependencies

In text form:

Oh no! Something has gone wrong.
A problem has occurred and the system can't recover.
All extensions have been disabled as a precaution.


You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details, or clues as to what changes you've made (especially those made in the session prior to problems) thus our ability to help is somewhat limited. Assuming you're using Ubuntu Desktop, what release are you using? and what change(s) did you make in the session before a problem occurred; and what changes have been made since then?  (dependency issues are usually the result of user error; trying to use packages built for a different product/releases; but you've provided no clues as to what was done initially and reversions attempted)

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour].
